# Where to store the state to make React components more reusable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an autocomplete component which has following props:

- `value` (display text),
- `onChange` (fired on every keystroke)
- `onSelect`(fired when user picks something from the list of
  suggestions, passes selected object + display text of selected object - the same as `value`)

state: 
 - `suggestionsList` (I've decided it's a state as it's something internal to the component).

On one of the views parent of this component doesn't care about the `value` after each keystroke. It just cares about the selected item passed by `onSelect` handler. So in this scenario `value` & `onChange` props are not needed. `value` could become an internal state of the autocomplete component.

But on one of the other views parent would like to also know about each keystrokes. This means the parent would need to hold the `value` in his state and also pass it as props. `onChange` props would be also needed to notify parent to change its state.

How to construct the autocomplete component so it handles both scenarios? Which properties should be props and which state?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The parent doesn't *need* to hold the value in its state, it just needs to provide an `onChange` handler from which you can retrieve the value. It *may* need to hold the value in its state, but it doesn't *have* to. So if the component receives an `onChange` property (function from parent) it needs to call it along with its own `onChange`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. That's a useful suggestion. Assuming the first scenario from the question: parent doesn't need `value`. I will change my component's `value` to be internal state and let parent be notified about selected item with `onSelect` props handler. Everything is fine so far.
What about the second scenario now (parent wants updates on each keystroke)? Should the parent pass `onChange` and save the value in its own state (`value` state would be then duplicated in both parent and child)? My goal is to write singe component which would handle both scenarios.

Comment: Yes, as stated, if the parent passes an `onChange` handler to the component, the component would need to call that as part of its internal `onChange` handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, if the parent needs to know about the current `value`, it doesn't need to hold the variable, so I guess that if you pass the current `value` (from an internal state variable) as a parameter to the `onChange` prop function, the parent will notice the change and update accordingly.

Another way to do it is to use the `value` property and a internal state variable. What I mean is: if the parent wishes to control the `value` it will have an state entry for it and will be responsible for updating it, in other case the `value` property must not be provided because it would end as a constant. Your component will use this property as the current value every time its provided, and the parent should use `onChange` to update the va;ue that it holds.

You can check the source code of the auto complete component in [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete).

Comment: So it seems I will follow the pattern to have `value` as an internal state and set it from props if provided. `onChange` will update both internal `value` state and call parent handler passed with props. I think that's the best way. Thanks